# Angularjs: How To Inject Controller Into Module After DOM Is Initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am injecting new DOM with controller:

```
app.controller('cart', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.content = {
        label: "hello, world!",
    };
});

var $html = '<div ng-controller="cart"></div>';
var $root = $('[ng-app]');

angular.element($root).injector().invoke(function ($compile) {
    var $scope = angular.element($root).scope();
    $root.append($compile($html)($scope));
    // Finally, refresh the watch expressions in the new element
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

In `$root.append($compile($html)($scope));` the error occurs. I can even see that the controller is registered on `app` when I debug it with Chrome.

What can go wrong with the code?

---

### EDIT

So if I put this way:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('base', function ($scope, $http) {
    ....
});

app.controller('cart', function ($scope, $http) {
    ....
});
```

in the same file, it works. My case is I have 2 separated js files. One file contains:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('base', function ($scope, $http) {
    ....
});
```

The file above gets loaded first. Then the second file has:

```
app.controller('cart', function ($scope, $http) {
    ....
});

var $html = '<div ng-controller="cart"></div>';
var $root = $('[ng-app]');

angular.element($root).injector().invoke(function ($compile) {
    var $scope = angular.element($root).scope();
    $root.append($compile($html)($scope));
    // Finally, refresh the watch expressions in the new element
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

and is loaded later after the first file is finished. So the question should be changed to:

How to inject a new controller to a module after the module got initialized?

Comment: The code works with this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/8y5f3PIC7QXlqWEMCyru?p=preview).

Comment: Both controllers are defined in different files. That causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the internet. It shows how to inject controllers, directives, filter, etc. after Angularjs has been bootstrapped. Call the `app.config()` after the module assignment.

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

    app.config(
        function( $controllerProvider, $provide, $compileProvider ) {
            // Since the "shorthand" methods for component
            // definitions are no longer valid, we can just
            // override them to use the providers for post-
            // bootstrap loading.
            console.log( "Config method executed." );
            // Let's keep the older references.
            app._controller = app.controller;
            app._service = app.service;
            app._factory = app.factory;
            app._value = app.value;
            app._directive = app.directive;
            // Provider-based controller.
            app.controller = function( name, constructor ) {
                $controllerProvider.register( name, constructor );
                return( this );
            };
            // Provider-based service.
            app.service = function( name, constructor ) {
                $provide.service( name, constructor );
                return( this );
            };
            // Provider-based factory.
            app.factory = function( name, factory ) {
                $provide.factory( name, factory );
                return( this );
            };
            // Provider-based value.
            app.value = function( name, value ) {
                $provide.value( name, value );
                return( this );
            };
            // Provider-based directive.
            app.directive = function( name, factory ) {
                $compileProvider.directive( name, factory );
                return( this );
            };
            // NOTE: You can do the same thing with the "filter"
            // and the "$filterProvider"; but, I don't really use
            // custom filters.
        }
    );
```

then do `app.controller('base', function ($scope, $http) { ....` or define filter/directives/etc. after this will work.

Here is the [link](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2553-loading-angularjs-components-after-your-application-has-been-bootstrapped.htm) by Ben Nadel.